# Trying to use Yahoo Fantasy Sports API with python but getting internal server error

Tags: python-3.x, yahoo-api

I'm trying to learn how to use the YahooApi, but when getting the data from the website, it gives me an internal server error. I have tried every combination of league or leagues data or even general game data, but everything is giving me an internal server error. I have attached my code below and any help I could receive would be very helpful.

```
import json
import time
import webbrowser
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from rauth import OAuth1Service
from rauth.utils import parse_utf8_qsl

credentials_file = open('auth.json')
credentials = json.load(credentials_file)
credentials_file.close()

oauth = OAuth1Service(consumer_key = 'key',
                  consumer_secret = 'secret',
                  name = "yahoo",
                  request_token_url = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token",
                  access_token_url = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token",
                  authorize_url = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth",
                  base_url = "http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/")

request_token, request_token_secret = oauth.get_request_token(params={"oauth_callback": "oob"})

authorize_url = oauth.get_authorize_url(request_token)
webbrowser.open(authorize_url)
verify = input('Enter code: ')

raw_access = oauth.get_raw_access_token(request_token,
                                    request_token_secret,
                                    params={"oauth_verifier": verify})


parsed_access_token = parse_utf8_qsl(raw_access.content)
access_token = (parsed_access_token['oauth_token'], 
parsed_access_token['oauth_token_secret'])

start_time = time.time()
end_time = start_time + 3600

credentials['access_token'] = parsed_access_token['oauth_token']
credentials['access_token_secret'] = parsed_access_token['oauth_token_secret']
tokens = (credentials['access_token'], credentials['access_token_secret'])


s = oauth.get_session(tokens)
r = s.get('https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/leagues;league_keys=nba.l.60379', params={'format': 'json'})

print(r.status_code)
r.json()
```

And that prints {u'error': {u'description': u'Internal server error', u'lang': u'en-US'}}

Comment: Please include your code as text and not as an image otherwise your question will not be answered and might get deleted from this site.

Comment: Fixed sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

seems like this issues stems from Yahoo's side. One user reported trying OAuth2 authentication which seemed to work fine.

https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Help-with-Fantasy-Baseball/Receiving-500-quot-Internal-Server-Error-quot-from-Yahoo-Fantasy/td-p/341427/page/4